# Video is not playing on AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

i'm trying to play video from url using `AVPlayer`.

but video is not playing.
because video url is "unsecure"(Not Secure).
but i've already allow `NSAppTransportSecurity`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

here viewController Code

```
  import AVKit
  import AVFoundation

  let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()


  let url =  Constants.API.imageURL + (GlobalVariables.sharedManager.userDetailObj.UserDetail?.intro_video_path)! //which is "http://23.97.79.216:8000/api/media/intro-video/video_file_2rg3tio.mp4"

  //let videoURL = URL(string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.m4v") //testing unsecure(Not Secure) url which is working.
  let videoURL = URL(string: url)
  let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
  playerViewController.player = player
  self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
     self.playerViewController.player!.play()
  }
```

as i mention in code that **"http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.m4v"** is unsecure(Not Secure) but its working fine.

but my url **"http://23.97.79.216:8000/api/media/intro-video/video_file_2rg3tio.mp4"** is not working.

there is any way that we can play video of unsecure(Not Secure) url?

Comment: @matt it will come from `Constants.API.imageURL + (GlobalVariables.sharedManager.userDetailObj.UserDetail?.intro_video_path)!`

Comment: @matt have you test my code?
please check again my code.

Comment: I think problem is not with your iOS code, May be your server have some issues. Try adding access control allowing all origin.

Comment: Is this link opening in safari?

Comment: @RajeshBudhiraja no its not working in Simulator safati.

Comment: If it's not working in safari it wont work in AVPlayer. Is it working in chrome? If no then url seems to be wrong

Comment: its only working in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that the link that's not working can not be upgraded to https.

**Why:**

iOS doesn't allow http url requests for security reasons.
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections)

This means that if you try to access a resource that uses **http** instead of **https** iOS will try to upgrade it automatically to https. If you go to the second link in your browser, and add the https transport protocol  the link will still work. That server can handle SSL connections (which are secure). However, your first link can not upgrade to https and will always fail.

**Solution**

If this server (the first, broken, link) is one you own, add SSL security. That's the easy fix. If you don't have access to it, you'll need to download the video and host it somewhere with SSL security.

**Workarounds**

Sadly there aren't any workarounds for this besides hosting it yourself. Apple simply does not allow http requests as they can open an attack on the user's device using a man-in-the middle attack.

Comment: Adding SSL to a server is free nowadays as well. There's no reason to not add it to your server if it is yours. https://letsencrypt.org/